# Copy file by type with folder structure

Tags: windows-8, file-transfer

I have a big tree of file something like

```
folderA
  folderB
    file.any
    file.txt
  folderC
  folderD
    folderE
      file.txt
      file.any
```

I need to copy all *.txt files with folder tree. How can I do that in windows 8? Is there some cmd command or any app?

Result of what I need:

```
folderA
  folderB
    file.txt
  folderD
    folderE
      file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `xcopy` in a CMD shell, eg:

```
xcopy /s {source-dir}\*.txt {target-dir}\
```

If you want to retain the full directory structure even when there are no *.txt files in the source `/e` will create empty directories.